# How to use WF (Windows Workflow Foundation) in a ASP.NET web application using C# as Server Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation

I searched online quite a while for the information (for beginners) on how to use Windows Workflow Foundation in a ASP.NET web application

I found a youtube video that, in my own opinion, is a worthwhile video to learn about Windows Workflow Foundation - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mqGhSH9xM4. However, the problem is that the demo inside the video is for C# Console application.

Is there anyone who can advise where I can find a simple video or tutorial (for beginners and similar like the video) that teach how to use Windows Workflow Foundation in a simple ASP.NET web application so that at least I can start from that point onwards.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use'? Do you want to know how host a workflow in IIS or how to interact with a workflow from within an ISS hosted website?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd meaning to incorporate the workflow into the web application. (example: I created the workflow inside the web application that will read two value and show me the result by perform a addition on the two value. the web application will contain a aspx that have two text box (to input two value) and 1 label box (to display the result) and 1 button. The overall process is that the user enter a value each into the 2 text box, click the button, the two value pass to the workflow and the workflow output the result into the label box in the aspx.)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Thanks Erno, I know you are trying hard to give me a solution that can help me but I am a beginner and still trying hard to "incorporate" the windows workflow into a simple asp.net web application using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you would use WF for long running processes so the scenario you describe in the comment is not a common thing to expect.

Pages should return quickly to the browser. The browser (javascript/ajax) could then poll the server for a result from the workflow and put it, when available, in the page.

In general I'd expect the webpage to start (or query the status of) a workflow. Hosting the workflow in the same IIS process might cause issues when the process is recycled.

[You could host a workflow in IIS (I prefer Appfabric)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729689.aspx)

If you implement it as a Workflow Service (using a [receive activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.workflow.activities.receiveactivity%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

you can [invoke it like any other WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb924504%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, in my own opinion, the example you give seem not suitable for beginners. I have not ideas how to create a simple web application that use windows workflow foundation (using Visual Studio 2008). The last link you provided - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb924504(v=vs.90).aspx looks close enough but however, it is for a console application, not asp.net web appplication. Wonder if there are really simple ones out there for beginner to start with.

Comment: WF is not for beginners. Calling a Windows Workflow Service is the same from a console and a web application.

Answer (score 0):

You may get idea to connect asp.net we form with the workflow

[Getting Started: Windows Workflow Foundation and ASP.NET](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5284.getting-started-windows-workflow-foundation-and-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76311080/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).